# How to get all the documents from elasticseach using a php-elasticsearch client

Tags: php, elasticsearch

In one of my index, I've got the 80000 documents. I'm trying to get all the data in a single hit. There is a maximum limit of 10000 data.

How do I can get all 80000 records at a time through php ?.

I'm referring this URL  https://packagist.org/packages/elasticsearch/elasticsearch

```
$params = [
    "scroll" => "30s",          
    "size" => 10000,               
    "index" => $stdIndex,
    'type' => $stdIndexType];

$response = $client->search($params);

while (isset($response['hits']['hits']) && count($response['hits']['hits']) > 0) {
$scroll_id = $response['_scroll_id'];
$response = $client->scroll([
        "scroll_id" => $scroll_id,
        "scroll" => "30s"]
);
}
```

Comment: You need to use the [scrolling feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/5.0/_search_operations.html#_scrolling)

Comment: Thanks for the replay. do you have any example to mention here with the php client? it would be very helpful.

Comment: There's a full blown example in the link I've shared

Comment: Thanks this looks good. I'll try it out and get back you.

Comment: please update your question with your code, it's more legible. The idea is to run your code, and when it stops, you should have 80K documents in your ES.

Comment: @Val Thanks This worked for me. Thanks a Lot

Comment: @Val - Is there any way to create a new index using php ES Client?

Comment: yes, feel free to ask a new question since it is not related to this question.

Comment: ok Fine. ill come up with my question.

Comment: @Val -I found one issue in the scroll, my first response is printing a set of data and it is different from the scroll response inside the while loop.